# Principed BSDF not work with texture image

Tags: texturing, shaders, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes

I am currently trying to achieve my terrain texture. So far no problem but not for the last texture.
Here's where I'm at right now (without any problem):
[image: texture rendering]

[image: texture node without problème]

Each group (GravelNode, LeaveNode…) Contains the same node pattern, for example:
[image: node group of grass]

My goal now is to add a texture with a mask for my road so I add a node and again a mix shader:
[image: added nodes]

But I get this on all my texture:
[image: rendering of the texture with the problem]

The origin of the problem comes from the group node grass gravel because when I put a base color constant there is no problem:
[image: node with constant base color]

[image: rendered with a base color constant]

The problem is always present when I directly link the color of the image texture to the base color of the principled BSDF or when I use another image.

Can you help me ?

**[EDIT]**

[image]

Comment: Can you upload your Blender file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably you have too many textures in one material. Eevee uses your GPU to render which has hardware limits in how many texture can be used at once.

If you check the console you'll probably see

```
ERROR (gpu.shader): GPU_material_compile Linking:
      | Error: Too many fragment shader texture samplers
```

There are 5 textures per group times 5 groups, plus 1 Texture Image node, plus 3 Color Ramp nodes (which count as textures), for at least 29 textures.

You can try using Cycles to avoid this limit.

Comment: Thank you, after some testing and research I found how I am going to do it. I will indeed go on cycles, as it may have another texture. But I noted that in material preview mode blender uses eevee so texture with the problem but not in display render mode if we use cycle. So I'm going to modify my shader to have two material outputs, one with textures for cycles and the other with constant colors for eevee (for material preview mode), to have a minimum understandable rendering in preview.